# SwiftUI - How to default the object state back to false when another object which is selected is true inside list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to update the function(isFavoriteToggle()) that when I select another object in the list the object which isFavorite state changed earlier to true get default back to false and this object isFavorite state to change to true.

For example when I select "item 1" from the list the isFavorite Boolean object state change to true.
If I select "item 3" in the list then "item 1" isFavorite state change back to false and "item 3" to true.

Basically I want one Item at a time in the list to be isFavorite state to true and all other is false.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Items: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool = false
    static var samples: [Items] = [
        Items(name: "item 1"),
        Items(name: "item 2"),
        Items(name: "item 3"),
        Items(name: "item 4"),
        Items(name: "item 5"),
        Items(name: "item 6"),
        Items(name: "item 7"),
    ]
}
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleList: View {
    @State var queryList: [Items] = Items.samples

    
    func isFavoriteToggle(element: Items) {
        guard let index = queryList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == element.id}) else {return}
        queryList[index].isFavorite.toggle()
        
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($queryList) { $list in
                    Button {
                        isFavoriteToggle(element: list)
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(list.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(list.isFavorite ? Color.yellow : Color.gray)
                        }
                    }

                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .padding()
            
            
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleList()
    }
}
```

Appreciate your support. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
struct ExampleList: View {
  
@State var queryList: [Items] = Items.samples

  func isFavoriteToggle(element: Items) {
    queryList.indices.forEach { index in
        queryList[index].isFavorite = false
    }
    guard let index = queryList.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == element.id }) else { return }
    queryList[index].isFavorite = true
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach($queryList) { $list in
                Button {
                    isFavoriteToggle(element: list)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(list.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(list.isFavorite ? Color.yellow : Color.gray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Test")
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .padding()
    }
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Inazuma. I have one issue now, that when I select the same row which object state is changed to true(isFavorite) is not changing back to false unless I select other row. For example if Item1 state is true when I select the same row again it’s not changing back to false. How can I also change state for the isFavorite in same row back to false.

Comment: Yes sure, you should change the isFavorite function like this func isFavoriteToggle(element: Items) {
        queryList.indices.forEach { index in
            queryList[index].isFavorite = (queryList[index].id == element.id)
        }
    }

Comment: Hi Hi @Inazuma. I updated the function but still is not changing the state to false. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a list can have one and only one favourite, then this feels like a single property to represent which item is the favourite, rather than a collection of interdependent boolean values.

Assuming that no item in the list is a favourite to begin with, you could go for something like:

```swift
struct ExampleList: View {
    @State var queryList: [Items] = Items.samples
    @State var favorite: Items?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($queryList) { $list in
                    Button {
                        favorite = list
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(list.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(list.id == favorite?.id ? Color.yellow : Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```